# Altering nodes title value

Tags: nodes, theming

I am trying to alter the title of my nodes to prevent URLS appearing in any title. This is the code I am using.

```
function mytemplate_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node '];
  $variables['title'] = cleaner(check_plain($node->title));
}
```

`cleaner()` removes URLs from nodes. The above works perfectly on teasers, but not on full view or when the title is displayed in a list with other articles inside a block.

How can I make sure that the URL disappear whenever the concerned node's title is listed?

Comment: You should do this cleanup in node_presave(https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7)

Comment: @Yaz: Have a got answer to your problem, and if found some other work around than please share. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement both

- template_preprocess_page() : this will take care of node full view mode.
- temaplte_proprocess_node() : this will take care of node teaser view mode

In your theme template.php

```
function mythemename_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if(isset($variables['node']) && $variables['node']->type == "your content type") {
    drupal_set_title("your_title");    
  }
}

/**
 * Override or insert variables into the node template.
 */
function mythemename_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if($variables['type'] == "your content type") {
    $variables['title'] = "your title";
  }
}
```

Note:

> - only changing in template_preprocess_node(), will now reflect on node teaser view as it will be overridden by page template.
> - in order to change  you should use drupal_set_title() instead of $variables['title'].

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly for the existing nodes, but for the new ones i ll use the above solution with node_presave

Comment: true, but its wiser according to me having one solution
as keeping the other two proprocess hooks will be fired anyway! so take your pick honestly I do not see difference between existing and new if you have all the codes put to work.Preferably you can dry run with node_save function keeping code mentioned in hook_node_presave() and remove the preprocess function from template file

Answer (score -1):

Use [template_preprocess_page()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7) in the template.php to update the page title for full view, However please don't your code for hook_preprocess_node() as that code would be required for updating the page title for teaser view.

Examples:

```
// Example of updating the nodes title for all content types.
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  // Check if the variable is of node type.
  if (!empty($vars['node']) {
    $updated_title = cleaner(check_plain($node->title));
    drupal_set_title($updated_title);
  }
}
```

To update the page title of specific page just update the `if` condition as below:

```
if (!empty($variables['node']) && $variables['node']->type == 'CONTENT_TYPE') {
  $updated_title = cleaner(check_plain($node->title));
  drupal_set_title($updated_title);
}
```

---

The above things will update the page title at the time of rendering, however the better solution is to clear the URL's from the node title before saving (insert/update) the node so that you wont need to modified at the time of rendering:

```
// Using the hook_node_presave() for removing the URL's from title.
function MyModule_node_presave($node) {
  $node->title = cleaner(check_plain($node->title));
}
```

**Note**: The hook_node_presave() will help you for new nodes and the nodes those you are going to update.

Comment: You shouldn't really call drupal_set_title() from a template like that. If you must, then put it in template_preprocess_page() in the tempalte.php, otherwise in a module in hook_node_view() or similar.

Comment: hook_view_pre_render is not suppose to use here!this hook is invoked jus before rendering a view

Comment: @arpitr He wants to update the title of his views too

Comment: you might be confusing with "The above works perfectly on teasers, but not on full view" node full view and view are two different things :)